# Highcharts Zoom to last 1000 points

Tags: highcharts

I'd like to turn dataGrouping on if the number of points is over 1000, but automatically zoom into the last 1000 points.

Has anyone done this yet and/or know of a way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Datagrouping**

Use condition to set the flag `enabled` in `plotOptions.series.dataGrouping` as

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
        dataGrouping: {
            enabled: data.length > 1000 ? true : false
        }
      }
    },
```

**Range 1000 last points**

Extract the last point as max and last point - 1000 as min, then call setExtremes()

```
var seriesData = data,
    lenSeries = seriesData.length - 1,
    max = seriesData[lenSeries][0],
    min = seriesData[lenSeries - 1000][0];

chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(min, max);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bwmcdg6w/